# What is the performance of the heap for allocating memory?

Tags: memory, heap-memory

Dynamically allocated memory comes from the stack or the heap. I've heard some people say that the heap is a linked list, although if this were the case, it would seem like it would be incredibly inefficient. For example, if you wanted to allocate a large block of memory, it seems that you might have to look through most of the list before finding something with free space. Also, over time the number of blocks with small amounts of free memory could just get larger and larger. As a result, the claimed big-O notation runtimes of some algorithms may not be true as they often rely on constant time allocations. Could anyone clarify how they are implemented and how efficient they are?

Comment: It's up to a particular runtime on how to deal with the heap. Performance is not an absolute characteristic of a system, nothing is universally fast or slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heaps are managed in different ways. You can find hundreds of different implementations of malloc on the internet. You can then pick the one that gets you the best performance in your application.

One way to do a heap is to only allocate blocks of fixed sizes. For example, your heap manager would maintain lists of blocks of say 16, 32, 64, ...... bytes. The heap manger just pulls the next available block that is larger than the size requested.